# What have we done that you should be so angry with us? - "that" clause of result？

Tags: archaic-language, content-clauses

Can "that" introduce an adverbial clause of result？
Do the following sentences sound natural to you?

1a: What have we done that you should be so angry with us?

1b: “Are you starving that you must steal?” said John to his son.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

*Clause of result* is an ambiguous term: it appears that in teaching English it is usually used of *so that* and *so/such...that* clauses, which may describe either a result or a *desired* result—a *purpose*. In these the *that* is often omitted.

> It was ***so*** hot ***(that)*** he took off his coat.
> He took off his coat ***so (that)*** he would be cooler.

Bare *that* was indeed used to express purpose in older English, with a following 'subjunctive' clause:

> He died ***that*** we might live.
> She works ***that*** her children may not starve.

Today, however, we use *so that* or bare *so*, and the subjunctive quality is usually weakened or eliminated:

> He died ***so (that)*** we would be able to live.
> She works ***so (that)*** her children won't starve.

This use, with bare *that*, is now purely literary, and largely confined to religious contexts, where the influence of the 17th century Authorized Version of the Bible is still strong.

The two sentences you give are a little different, though they are grounded in the same idiom. In both, the *that* clause expresses a result, but it is not a *desired* result: it is an existing state for which the speaker seeks a cause.

> *What have we done that you should be so angry with us?*
> = Why you are so angry? What did we do to cause that?
>
> *Are you starving that you must steal?*
> Why must you steal? Is it because you are starving?

The first is fairly colloquial, though today a *for* clause would be a little more likely: *What have we done **for you to be** so angry with us?*. The second, however, is decidedly literary; in colloquial speech *must* would become *have to* and the question suggesting the cause would be recast with an explicit ‘cause’ term:

> Is it ***because*** you are starving that you have to steal?
> Are you starving? Is that ***why*** you have to steal?

Answer (score 1):

Both your answers are correct, albeit extremely literary and outdated (almost Shakespearian).

More contemporary usage would be:

> What have we done to make you so angry with us? -*or*- What have we done for you to be so angry with us?
>
> Are you starving to the point that you have to steal? -*or*- Are you so hungry that you have to steal?